# C# INotifyPropertyChanged from observablecollection's item

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

To put simply I am trying to get my view to update when i modify the property of an item in an observable collection. The observable collection handle when I modify add/remove items in it, but not when I modify one of the values.

In the ViewModel I have this Observable collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<ListItem> Items
    {
        get { return primaryBin.Items; }
        set { primaryBin.Items = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

And in the code, I call this:

```
                if (Found) 
                {
                    viewModel.IsBusy = true;

                    //Check if there are already some of this product received
                    ListItem origin = viewModel.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.EAN == labelText);

                    updateErp = false;
                    SupplierOrderLineForScan p = viewModel.lines.FirstOrDefault(pr => pr.Ean.Trim() == labelText.Trim());
                    u = await Common.GetPickingUser();

                    //Check if there is already some of this product on the trolley
                    ListItem bincontentDirection = viewModel.NotCurrentItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.EAN == labelText);
                    BinContent bincontentOrigin = viewModel.NotCurrentBinContents.Find(s => s.StockId == p.StockId);


                    if (bincontentDirection == default(ListItem))
                    {
                        bincontentDirection = new ListItem { 
                            Quantity = 0
                            , EAN = origin.EAN, Name = origin.Name};
                        viewModel.ItemsTransfer.Add(bincontentDirection);
                    }
                    bincontentDirection.Quantity++;
                    origin.Quantity--;

                }
```

But when I modify the quantity in the "origin" (which is an item from the observable collection) it does not refresh the view.

I've tried wrapping my head around the issue, but despite all the post I've read about it, it doesn't click. Observable collection handles add/remove natively, I have something in the Basic viewmodel to handle modification in the items but nothing seems to work.

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
        [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Edit: Adding the Model of the ListItem

```
public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
public class ListItem : BaseModel
{
    //BinConten id
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Block { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsBlockIconVisible { get; set; }
    public string CodeSupplier { get; set; }
    public bool IsHeader { get; set; }
    public string Entry { get; set; }
    public String ProductID { get; set; }
    public bool showDeleteButton { get; set; }
    public bool showTransferButton { get; set; }
    public int BinID { get; set; }
    public int Piece { get; set; }

    private int _quantity;
    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return _quantity; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _quantity, value); }
    }

    public int BookedQuantity { get; set; }

    public int QuantityDefect { get; set; }

    public Color bgColor { get; set; }

    int _quantityDefect;
    public string EAN { get; set; }

    public string QuantityDisplay
    {
        get { return $"Q: {Quantity}(@{BookedQuantity})"; }
    }

    public string QuantityExpectedDisplay
    {
        get { return $"{Quantity} / {BookedQuantity}"; }
    }

    public string EANReference
    {
        get { return $"{EAN} / {CodeSupplier}"; }
    }

    public Style Style { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to set up the item in the collection as a viewmodel. The collection observes the items but not the data inside the items.

Comment: Is Quantity a property and does it fire the PropertyChanged event? How is it bound to the View?

Comment: @PaulPalmpje I am not sure I follow. I already tried adding the Inotify to the List Item, but to no avail. I also made sure to add a line to update the handler when in the ListItem. And I have checked, I do go trough the Listitem's Onproperty changed.

if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

Comment: @Dizzy I updated the original post with the model. Quantity Does fire the Property Changed Event.

It is bound to the biew by creating a viewmodel in the cs part of the view and setting it up as BindingContext. I display it by binding "Items" to a Listview and binding the text of a label with the "QuantityDisplay" of the item... I'll try to check if it's actually because of the indirect binding.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I found my issue. I was updating the Quantity properly, but my binding was on a displpay value (QuantityDisplay) which was not updated.

Comment: Well done, did you change the view to bind to Quantity or add a setter to QuantityDisplay and fire PropertyChangeEvent on it?

Comment: @Dizzy Both. I Binded to Quantity to check if it was the issue and once I confirmed it worked, I fired PropertyChanged on QuantityDisplay when Quantity was modified. I did understand how it works, I just wasn't working with the right things. Thank you for the help ;-)